# How do I force iron-router to react when the hash has not apparently changed?

Tags: hash, meteor, iron-router

When using iron-router to scroll to a hash using an anchor button referencing the id of the next section, such as this:

```
<a class="button" href="{{pathFor 'home' hash='about'}}">
```

iron-router happily takes us to the about section the first time the button is clicked.

if you scroll back up using the mouse and click the same button a second time, no scrolling takes place.

I presume this is because the destination is apparently the same as the current router location, hence no reaction is triggered.

How can I force a reaction?

I've tried clearing the hash in the window.location in an override to the scrollToHash function:

```
Router._scrollToHash = function(hash) {
  var section = $(hash);
  if (section.length) {
    var sectionTop = section.offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: sectionTop
    }, "slow");
  }
  window.location.hash = '';
};
```

And this allows a second click but no more, which has me puzzled.

Comment: isn't this more of a browser question than an iron-router question? iron router just sets the href according to `pathFor`, how your browser interprets clicking on such a link is sort of up to the browser.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the browser should detect when we scroll out of a section denoted by the hash and change the hash value? I don't think that is expected behaviour - I think the problem is that the scrollToHash function is only invoked when there is a change of hash, or rather when the hash changes from that of the current router location - so I either need to change the hash in the window or reset the current router location in order to make a difference that will set off the scroll function. setting the hash to null works once but only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting window.location.hash to a space rather than an empty string works:

```
Router._scrollToHash = function(hash) {
  var section = $(hash);
  if (section.length) {
    var sectionTop = section.offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: sectionTop
    }, "slow");
  }
  window.location.hash = ' ';

};
```

Probably setting it to a non-existent hash would also.

In addition to cover cases where there is a menu link that can be activated from a second page to take you to the hash you need this package:

```
meteor add okgrow:iron-router-autoscroll
```

Used in combination it covers every case I have thought of.